# Actionscript Get XML Element By Dynamic Tag

Tags: xml, string, dynamic, actionscript, tags

I know that I can access an XML Element with tag name 'page' like so:

```
xml_variable.page[i].toString();
```

This is not what I want, however.

What I want to do is access the XML Element with the tag name equal to a String variable in Actionscript:

```
var page:String = getCurrentPage();
xml_variable.page[i].toString());
```

I've done this in javascript and am wondering if it is possible in Actionscript 3. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
xml_variable[page][i].toString();
```